# Can I assign data from object that is created to child class object variable?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am trying to finish an assignment that was given about creating a Library Management System using classes and objects only.
I have completed the librarian class and its methods which are mostly being inherited from the catalog class which have almost all the methods for managing the library catalog.

Now on creating the User class after inheriting the Librarian class, when I create a member object and try to access a method `member.displayAllBooks()`, it gives the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'different_book_count'`

So Is there a way that I can assign `librarian.different_body_count` to member object?

**Catalog.py**

```
from Book import Book

class Catalog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.different_book_count = 0
        self.books = []

    #Only available to admin
    def _addBook(self, name, author, publish_date, pages):
        book = Book(name, author, publish_date, pages)
        self.different_book_count += 1
        self.books.append(book)
        return book

    #Only available to admin
    def _addBookItem(self, book, isbn, rack):
        book.addBookItem(isbn, rack)

    def searchByName(self, name):
        for book in self.books:
            if name.strip() == book.name:
                return book

    def searchByAuthor(self, author):
        for book in self.books:
            if author.strip() == book.author:
                return book

    def displayAllBooks(self):
        print('Books in catalog:', self.different_book_count)
        c = 0
        for book in self.books:
            c += book.total_count
            book.printBook()

        print('Total Book Count:', c)

    def _removeBookItem(self, name, isbn):
        book = self.searchByName(name)
        book_item = book.searchBookItem(isbn)
        book.removeBookItem(book_item)

    def _removeBookFromCatalog(self, name):
        book = self.searchByName(name)
        self.books.remove(book)
        self.different_book_count -= 1
        del book
```

**User.py**

```
from Catalog import Catalog
from Book import Book

class User:
    def __init__(self, name, location, age, aadhar_id):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.age = age
        self.aadhar_id = aadhar_id

class Librarian(User, Catalog):
    def __init__(self, name, location, age, aadhar_id, emp_id):
        super().__init__(name, location, age, aadhar_id)
        Catalog.__init__(self)
        self.emp_id = emp_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + self.location + self.emp_id

    def addBook(self, name, author, publish_date, pages):
        book = Book(name, author, publish_date, pages)
        self.different_book_count += 1
        self.books.append(book)
        return book

    def addBookItem(self, book, isbn, rack):
        super()._addBookItem(book, isbn, rack)

    def removeBookItem(self, name, isbn):
        super()._removeBookItem(name, isbn)

    def removeBookFromCatalog(self, name):
        super()._removeBookFromCatalog(name)

class Member(Librarian, Catalog):
    def __init__(self, name, location, age, aadhar_id, student_id):
        User.__init__(self, name, location, age, aadhar_id)
        self.student_id = student_id
        # self.different_book_count = super().different_book_count
        # self.books = super().books

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.location + ' ' + self.student_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you never called `Catalog.__init__`, so all attributes of the `Catalog` class never appear in your inherited classes.

Why do I reach that conclusion?

Because your `super().__init__` calls have arguments; `Catalog.__init__` does not support arguments.

For classes that inherit from `Catalog`, you have to invoke `Catalog`'s `__init__` directly.

Comment: But using the Catalog.__init__ directly inside member class would create a new catalog object for me right? (I tried it too, so can confirm that)

Comment: @AshishKaul well, no. Calling `Catalog()` -- equivalent to `Catalog.__new__()` -- creates a new catalog object. Calling `Catalog.__init__()` intializes the attributes. Don't mix the two.